# Common module bundler for Nodejs, Angular 2.0 and Ionic 2.0

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic2

I am going to start development of my new product. This product is going to have following tech stack

```
1. Nodejs
2. Angular js 2.0
3. IONIC 2.0
```

I want to use one module bundler for Node, Angular and Ionic so that I can write the common modules which can be re-purpose.  I am facing problem due to following reasons.

```
1. Nodejs uses native CommonJS module bundler. 
2. Angular 2.0 uses Typescript as native module bundler
3. Ionic 2.0 uses Typescript as native module bundler
```

I read a lot on ES6 vs TypeScript vs Commonjs but got more confused. This is very difficult for me to decide. In my last project, I was using Nodejs, Angular 1.x and ionic 1.x. I was very happy in my last project as I was using CommonJS pattern everywhere and used Webpack for compilation for Angular & Ionic code.

What is option for me for Nodejs, Angular 2.0 and ionic 2.0?

Please advice.

Comment: Do you have a project posted in Github using Ionic 1.x and Webpack?

Comment: I haven't use ionic 1.x with webpack, but have used angular 1.x with webpack in my current project.

Comment: Your project is open source? Do you can share?

Comment: Though it is on Github but not in public repo. I can't share entire code however I can share the code snippet which uses webpack. For example gulpfile.js, angular code, few views, few directives etc. Not sure how i can share with you. May be your email id?

Comment: My email: danielqmalta@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about one bundler, but as things are changing I found the Ionic Conference example app cleared up some of my confusion. There's a typescript-specific branch:
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/tree/typescript.

Comment: Keeping in mind native support of TypeScript for Angular 2.0 & Ionic 2.0, I am thinking to use TypeScript for Nodejs as well. Did some search on google and I do see people are trying Typescript for Nodejs. I will see how I will make progress.